# How many elements inserted by the user in an array?

Tags: c, arrays

Suppose I declared an array as following:

```
int myArr = [someSize];
```

Now I put n elements **(where n is not known exactly but n < someSize)** in it like this

```
 myArray[0] = 12;
 myArray[1] = 23;
 and so on .....
```

Now I want to know is there any way to find out exactly how many elements have been entered by the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that there is some value that can't be put into the array (i.e. it is checked and disallowed beforehand), then you can initialise every element of the array to that, and then just do a count. e.g. if the array is initialised to `-1`:

```
int count = 0;
for (i = 0; i < someSize; i++) {
    if (myArr[i] != -1) count++;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't get any such information from the array. If you need it, you'll want to record it. When I've needed this, I've usually used something like:

```
struct myArray_t { 
    size_t next_element;
    int arr[somesize];
};
```

When you create this, you set `next_element` to 0, and to add an element, you use something like `myArr.arr[myArr.next_element++] = whatever;`

Answer (score 2):

No, if that's all you have you can't figure it out.  C does not internally store the number of array elements written to.